# On change events of the DOcument in brackets

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to find the onChange method of the Document object in Adobe Brackets but I can't find it, I need an eventListener that triggers everytime I press a key on my active document in brackets. Anybody knows how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Brackets API.
The Editor has an `keypress` Event:
http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/editor/Editor.html

You could use it like this:

```
function keyHandler(BracketsEvent, Editor, KeyboardEvent) {
    return;
}

var EditorManager = brackets.getModule('editor/EditorManager');
EditorManager.on('activeEditorChange', function (e, editorGainingFocus, editorLosingFocus) {
    if (editorLosingFocus) {
        editorLosingFocus.off('keypress', keyHandler);
    }
    if (editorGainingFocus) {
        editorGainingFocus.on('keypress', keyHandler);
    }
});
```